# Display a checkbox only once instead of multiple times

Tags: angular, html, typescript

I have a NgFor loop to create Distinct Card the headers tab and then iterate through the elements and put the info in respective card types. If there is a new type of data then I create a new header and put the info in that tab.

HTML Code:

```
          <mat-tab-group>
          <mat-tab *ngFor="let address of distinctAdressType" label="{{ address }}">
          <div *ngFor="let element of sampleData.address">
          <div *ngIf="address.toString() === element.addressType">
          <mat-label>
          <span>Address: {{ element.addressLine1 + ' ' + element.addressLine2 + ' ' + element.addressLine3 }}</span>
          </mat-label>
          <br />
          <mat-label> City: {{ element.city }}</mat-label> <br />
          <br />
          </div>
          </div>
          </mat-tab>
          </mat-tab-group>
```

I want to display a mat-checkbox however if I write the code then I get multiple checkbox for each address I get one checkbox.However I want a single checkbox.How do I achieve that.In mat-table I could have used index to show checkbox only on first row but how do I do it here? 
[image]

Instead of multiple checkbox for each row I just want a single checkbox on first row.

Answer (score 0):

Put the **mat-checkbox** tag outside of *ngFor tags under the **mat-tab** exit tag and use css on that tag e.g. `float: right`

Answer (score 0):

You have check index of loop, i just update your code i hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```
<mat-tab-group>
   <mat-tab *ngFor="let address of distinctAdressType" label="{{ address }}">
      <div *ngFor="let element of sampleData.address; let i = index">
        <md-checkbox *ngIf="i == 0">Checkbox Text</md-checkbox>
        <div *ngIf="address.toString() === element.addressType">
          <mat-label>
            <span>Address: {{ element.addressLine1 + ' ' + element.addressLine2 + ' ' + element.addressLine3 }}</span>
          </mat-label>
          <br />
          <mat-label> City: {{ element.city }}</mat-label> <br />
          <br />
       </div>
    </div>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```